# Accessing Facebook Profile URLs

Tags: python, facebook

The goal here, given a user facebook profile url, access and open the profile page. Some simple python code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
url = "http://www.facebook.com/username"
page = urlopen(url)
```

The problem is that for some "username" this causes HTTP ERROR 404. I noticed this error only happening when the path includes a name rather than the "profile.php?id=XXX" format.

Notice that we only have the url here and not the user id.

UPDATE:
This turned out to happen also for some of the "profile.php?id=XXX" and other username formats.

Answer (score 1):

This is a privacy feature of Facebook.  Users have the ability to hide their profile page so that only logged in users can view their page.  Accessing the page with `/profile.php?id=XXX` or with `/username` makes no difference.  You must be logged-in in order to view the HTML page.

In your context, you'd have to first log in to a valid Facebook account before requesting the page and you should no longer receive the 404's.

One way to check this is on the graph API, `graph.facebook.com/USERNAME` will return a `link` property in the resulting JSON if they have a public page, and it will be omitted on private pages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open the page in a Web Browser or access the HTML source generated by the page?

If the latter, have you thought of using the Facebook Graph API to achieve whatever it is that you are doing? This will be much faster and the API is all documented. Plus the page's HTML source could change at any point in time, whereas the Graph API will not.

**Edit**

You could use the Graph API without having to even create an application to get the user ID, but going to http://graph.facebook.com/username and parsing the JSON response. You can then access the profile HTML using http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=userId

Comment: I am trying to access the HTML source itself. Notice that all I have is the page URL, I don't have the id and I am assuming any page, not a logged in user page, so not sure Graph API will work in this case.

Comment: Ah, yes you can't get the HTML source from the Graph API. The Graph API can get the page by the url though, just the same as a normal page - http://graph.facebook.com/username

Comment: graph.facebook.com/username returns a JSON list with some info like the user id. That's a good point though for getting the user id. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, assuming you can access `profile.php?id=XXX` you could get the user id from the Graph API, then request that page. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Good point, but I actually noticed that some of the profile.php?id=XXX also have the same issue!

Comment: Have you opened the same URL in your web browser? Scan the headers and see if the HTTP status code is 404? Can you give an example of an ID that doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think I figured out what's the problem here. It's based on the user privacy policy. If you are not logged in to facebook, you will also get 404 for those users that are disabling public access. It's a bit confusing, since the server application itself has a user object with a valid access_token, but I guess facebook is doing this so that search engines cannot show these user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Not every Facebook account is accessible as FIRST.LAST, so you won't be able to reliably do this.

There is currently no guarantee that an account is accessible with a vanity name.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about a URL that I can already open in the browser. The problem is that I cannot access it using code.

Comment: That's quite odd: perhaps you need to play with the User-Agent string you send. I've not seen that be an issue before, but if it works in the browser the only thing I can think of is some form of user-agent sniffing on their part to attempt to prevent the dumber screen scrapers from succeeding. Does it work for ANY `FIRST.LAST` pages?

Comment: If you have a terminal, what does `wget -S -O - {url}` print out for one of the ones that works and one of the ones that doesn't?

Comment: Very odd: not sure what to tell you. Might just be a Facebook system error. I've noticed I occasionally have API requests that timeout and when I refresh the page they suddenly work. Are the failures at least consistently occuring (so the page that doesn't work NEVER works, and the page that does ALWAYS works)?

Comment: It seems consistent till now. Even for "profile.php?id=XXX" it has different response for different ids. For some ids, it returns the profile page, for some it redirects so the page you get is a general facebook page that lacks the profile content, and for some it returns the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine as long as the username exists.